# content overflow in display:inline-block; why and how?

Tags: html, css

Having this setup:

```html
<div>
    <label>...</label><br />
    <!-- repeat several times -->
</div>
```

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;

    max-height:3em; /* short enough to cause overflow */
    /* or, in Chrome, this works too: */
    padding:1ex;
}
```

will cause Chrome and Firefox to produce **horizontal** scrollbar:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJCU5/1/)

[image: screenshot of three browsers]

That Opera is Opera Presto, not Opera Blink. Too bad it's abandoned.

Anyway, why would this happen, and how would I get rid of the horizontal scrollbar if I need  both `max-height` (thus auto overflow) and `padding`?

P.S. I'm using an XP machine (company restriction), if that matters.

P.S.#2 Further testing shows that disabling `margin` on `<label>`s puts out the horizontal scrollbar in Firefox, but the content will be crudely <del>cut down to 3 characters length (the shortest label)</del>cut down about 2 characters (the width of scrollbar).

---

**Update #2:**

In case people feel ambiguous:

Why would the container `<div>` <del>shrink to the shortest length of its child (in this case, 3 chars)</del> expand no more than the width of content in Chrome and Firefox, excluding scrollbar, letting long childs overflow?
There's no length info anywhere, so what's the logic here? <del>I purposely added "Zero" so the first child is not the shortest one, but still got the same result.</del>

Opera Presto seems to work as I expected, but that does not seem to be the *de facto* standard.

And how could I ask `<div>` to expand to as wide as it should, while still keeping a max-height and auto scroll?

---

**Update #1:**

The direct cause of scrollbar is of course content horizontally overflowed, so if I brutally apply `overflow-x:hidden` to `<div>`, the result will simply be this:

[image: screenshot #2]

---

**Update #3:**

Thanks to @SergiyT., this turns out to be how Chrome and Firefox handles scrollbar, not the shortest child:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJCU5/3/)

[image: screenshot #3]

I'm not sure if this is "right" (content has been overflow-ed before the longest child appear), but this seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is how browsers work with scrollbars. It looks like opera (and maybe IE also) consider width/height without scrollbars but Firefox and Chrome take scrollbars into account. On your screenshot div width in Opera is bigger than in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: But there's no length info anywhere that will restrict `div` from expanding (not to mention I explicitly added `width:auto`). Why would Chrome and Firefox choose to simply cover the content with scrollbar, while still preserving the shortest length? And how could I get around this?

Comment: @Passerby I have no answer to your question. But I think that Firefox or Chrome count block width before applying `overflow:auto` or `max-height:3em`. After vertical scrollbar is added, block width is not changed, that is why horizontal scrollbar appears.

Comment: Well, further testing show that it's not the shortest label that matters, but really the scrollbar, so +1 for you. But still I need to get around this...

Comment: @Passerby Maybe you can overcome that with javascript (check div width and content of that div width and update div width if necessary) or declare `min-width` for div which is slightly bigger than content widt.

Comment: That would be Plan B. But thanks for pointing out the scrollbar issue, which makes me think this may be a dead end (or bug). Please excuse me for some minute before giving you the tick :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
div.listbox {    
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This will cause long labels be cut down. If you look at my screenshot, "Zero", "Three", "Four" and "Five" are overflowed to fit the shortest length (3 chars), that's why horizontal scrollbar appears. Applying `overflow-x:hidden` will simply cut them down.

Comment: It is still not clear for me what are you trying to reach.
but check this [Jsfiddle:update](http://jsfiddle.net/SJCU5/2/),where i added `margin-right: 18px;` to `div.listbox > input[type="radio"] + label `

Comment: I've updated my question. Edit: That will cause some extra space for "normal" browsers like Opera Presto, plus the `18px` for scrollbar width will be very platform-and-browser-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div.listbox{
...
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```